# How to load preexist sqlite file with MagicalRecord?

Tags: ios, sqlite, magicalrecord

I've prebuilt a Core Data specific sqlite file using some scripts I found online. 
I then try to use the file as my default sqlite database by inserting

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"database.sqlite"];
```

in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. But when I launch my app, it seem to create an empty database. I'm just wonder what is the correct method to load a prebuilt sqlite database using MagicalRecord?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up following the tutorial from [this](http://www.readncode.com/blog/Load-SQLite-db-into-Core-Data-in-iOS-5/). The main method is the persistentStoreCoordinator. Also, in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, instead of

```
PatientTableViewController *controller = (PatientTableViewController *)masterNavigationController.topViewController;
controller.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

I put

```
[self managedObjectContext];
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"database.sqlite"];
```

Also have to remember to chnage the sqlite file and the data model file (.xcdatamodeld) to the one I have.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your previous data store is in {App Folder}/Library/Application Support/{App Name}/database.sqlite. If your store is not there, MagicalRecord (really, Core Data) will create a new one for you.

If you want your store to be somewhere else, you can use the following method:

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreAtURL:<NSURL to your store>];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I called setupCoreDataStackWithStoreAtURL, it said no known class method for selector 'setupCoreDataStackWithStoreAtURL'. Seems like it could not find this method.

Comment: Look at the headers for the exact method

Comment: How do I write my sqlite file into /Library/Application Support folder? because I read from somewhere that we are not allow to write in that folder. And I couldn't not find the method for defining a alternative sqlite file. Is it setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed?